# custom html encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a custom encoding/decoding function in javascript.
I found a website who using this, but I am only able to found their decoding function

```
    var END_OF_INPUT = -1;
    var arrChrs = new Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "+", "/");
    var reversegetFChars = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrChrs.length; i++) {
    reversegetFChars[arrChrs[i]] = i
    }
    var getFStr;
    var getFCount;

    function ntos(e) {
         e = e.toString(16);
         if (e.length == 1) e = "0" + e;
         e = "%" + e;
         return unescape(e)
    }

    function readReversegetF() {
         if (!getFStr) return END_OF_INPUT;
         while (true) {
           if (getFCount >= getFStr.length) return END_OF_INPUT;
           var e = getFStr.charAt(getFCount);
           getFCount++;
           if (reversegetFChars[e]) {
            return reversegetFChars[e]
           }
           if (e == "A") return 0
        }
        return END_OF_INPUT
      }

      function readgetF() {
           if (!getFStr) return END_OF_INPUT;
           if (getFCount >= getFStr.length) return END_OF_INPUT;
           var e = getFStr.charCodeAt(getFCount) & 255;
           getFCount++;
    return e
}

function setgetFStr(e) {
    getFStr = e;
    getFCount = 0
}

function getF(e) {
    setgetFStr(e);
    var t = "";
    var n = new Array(4);
    var r = false;
    while (!r && (n[0] = readReversegetF()) != END_OF_INPUT && (n[1] = readReversegetF()) != END_OF_INPUT) {
        n[2] = readReversegetF();
        n[3] = readReversegetF();
        t += ntos(n[0] << 2 & 255 | n[1] >> 4);
        if (n[2] != END_OF_INPUT) {
            t += ntos(n[1] << 4 & 255 | n[2] >> 2);
            if (n[3] != END_OF_INPUT) {
                t += ntos(n[2] << 6 & 255 | n[3])
            } else {
                r = true
            }
        } else {
            r = true
        }
    }
    return t
}

function doit(e) {
    var v = unescape(getF(getF(e)))
}
```

They are posting this string to the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(doit('UEdsbWNtRnRaU0J6Y21NOUltaDBkSEE2THk5MGFHVjJhV1JsYjNNdWRIWXZaVzFpWldRdGJEaHBjelo0ZEhSMGVIUnlMVGN5T0hnME1UQXVhSFJ0YkNJZ2QyVmlhMmwwUVd4c2IzZEdkV3hzVTJOeVpXVnVQU0owY25WbElpQnRiM3BoYkd4dmQyWjFiR3h6WTNKbFpXNDlJblJ5ZFdVaUlHRnNiRzkzWm5Wc2JITmpjbVZsYmowaWRISjFaU0lnWm5KaGJXVmliM0prWlhJOUlqQWlJRzFoY21kcGJuZHBaSFJvUFNJd0lpQnRZWEpuYVc1b1pXbG5hSFE5SWpBaUlITmpjbTlzYkdsdVp6MGlibThpSUhkcFpIUm9QU0kzTWpnaUlHaGxhV2RvZEQwaU5ERXdJajQ4TDJsbWNtRnRaVDQ9'));</script>
```

and getting this output

```
<iframe src="http://thevideos.tv/embed-l8is6xtttxtr-728x410.html" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="728" height="410"></iframe>
```

I require an example how I can encode this type of string in javasript, any example/help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is decoding the base64_encoded string.